# Jasper Report : Resource not found

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, subreport

I am developing using Netbeans 7.1.

In my jasper report I have subreport in it.
It works in one place perfectly. I copied and pasted in another place and now shows this error :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : D:\ShareMarket\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\custom\kksharemarket/contractDetail.jasper
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResource(RepositoryUtil.java:155)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:126)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:317)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:347)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:275)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:473)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2021)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:265)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:281)
at org.apache.jsp.reportmgr_jsp._jspService(reportmgr_jsp.java:966)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Krushnakant, Just a quick note  D:\ShareMarket\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\custom\kksharemarket/contractDetail.jasper doe not look right because of the / before the subreport name.

Comment: @Krushnakant You can see this posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825726/how-to-load-subreport-resources-with-jasper & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785451/generate-jasper-report-with-subreport-from-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path `D:\ShareMarket\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\custom\kksharemarket` is suspicious. It should be `/custom/kksharemarket` because it lies in the class path of your application. The application probably is packed in a jar/war, and a file path will not do. Probably the resource is fetched not via the file system too, but on the class path. That normally is what "resource" means in java terms.

It worked on first development, because the directory structure was present.

Answer (score 1):

```
D:\ShareMarket\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\custom\kksharemarket/contractDetail.jasper

                                                            ^^^
```

I guess you hard-coded file separator when composing the jasper file path.